# Android synchronizing threads

Tags: android

My code have more than one thread and `Runnable`. My problem is i change the value of a certain variable in the thread that the `Runnable` calling .

After the calling i make a check on that variable value but the value was not retrieved yet.

How can i retrieve the value after the processing? Here is the `Runnable` and the `Thread` code:

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        if(flag==true)
        onSwipe();

        if(SwipeAgain==true)
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

private void onSwipe() {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            String data = null;
            decryption_data = null;
            encryption_data = null;
            SwipeAgain=false;
            handler.post(clear_encryption);
            try {
                data = sreader.ReadCard(15000);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if (ex instanceof TimeoutException) {
                    return;
                } else
                CloseSinWave();
            }

            if (data == null) {
                SwipeAgain=true;
                encryption_data = sreader.GetErrorString();
                if (encryption_data.equalsIgnoreCase("cancel all"))
                    return;
                handler.post(display_encryptiondata);
            } else {
                encryption_data = "\n" + data;
                handler.post(display_encryptiondata);

    }.start();
}
```

`SwipeAgain` is the value i want after processing

Comment: please delete irrelevant code in your listing to make it easier to read

Comment: ok i deleted most of the irrelevant code is this better

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Callable`, `Runnable` interface do not pass values to the parent method.

See this [example](http://www.journaldev.com/1090/java-callable-future-example).

You may require to use `Generic` Objects

Answer (score 0):

Use a MONITOR final Object to wait and notify it when processing is done.

```
private final MONITOR Object[] = new Object[0];
private AtomicBoolean ready = new AtomicBoolean(false);

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() 
    {
        if(flag==true){
            ready.set(false);
            onSwipe();
            synchronized(MONITOR){
                if(!ready.get()){
                    try{
                        MONITOR.wait();  //will block until it get notified
                    }catch(InteruptedException e){}
                }
            }
        }
        if(SwipeAgain==true)
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

private void onSwipe() {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
          try{
            String data = null;
            decryption_data = null;
            encryption_data = null;
            SwipeAgain=false;
            handler.post(clear_encryption);
            try {
                data = sreader.ReadCard(15000);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if (ex instanceof TimeoutException) {
                    return;
                } else
                    CloseSinWave();
            }

            if (data == null) {
                SwipeAgain=true;
                encryption_data = sreader.GetErrorString();
                if (encryption_data.equalsIgnoreCase("cancel all"))
                    return;
                handler.post(display_encryptiondata);
            } else {
                encryption_data = "\n" + data;
                handler.post(display_encryptiondata);
          }finally{
              synchronized(MONITOR){
                  ready.set(true);
                  MONITOR.notifyAll();  //notify (and so unblock r.run())
              }
          }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: no its not working i tried what you said but now onswip function are not working

Comment: oups... I forgot block delimiters. Can you check again ?

Comment: @ben75 For me, this approach is slower [visually, because my application is GLRendering]than handler.dispatchMessage, and running the required inside's handler.